# A Multivariable Distribution ($k$-dimension) with a given sum $m$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, entropy

I am wondering if there exists a distribution of $k$ positive random variables and their sum is a given deterministic scalar, say $m$. Mathematically, I am finding the following distribution:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1,\cdots,X_k),\quad s.t. \quad X_1+\cdots+X_k=m.
$$
I am hoping that this distribution has a parameter which is like the variation parameter $\sigma^2$ in Gaussian distribution, that can characterize the variation of the $k$ random variables.

**My thoughts**

Entropy might be a good metric to describe the variation of such $k$ random variables.
However, I do not know how to generate those $k$ *random variables* that satisfy their summation being $m$, and their entropy being, say $h$.

This is just my thoughts. If there are any similar distributions and have the desired parameter, please let me know. Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like a symmetric [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution), i.e. with equal concentration parameter, may be the kind of thing you are looking for.

You can generate them as $k$ Gamma random variables and then divide by their sum.  That would then add up to $1$, so you may want to multiply by $m$.

Comment: Thx for answering. If I get your idea correct, I should generate $k$ random variables from $\Gamma(\alpha,1)$, and then, normalize them so that their summation is $1$. This will ensure the normalized $k$ variables follow symmetric Dirichlet distribution with parameter $\alpha$. $\alpha$ controls the "variation" of the $k$ variables: larger $\alpha$ means that the $k$ variables are more similar to each other, right?

Comment: @Yuejiang_Li - Yes